# How to make scrollable div with fixed main screen?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put a table form in a div. The condition is that the main screen should not scroll, only inner `<div>` should scroll.

[image: In the image you can see 3 parts, p div child]

`<p>` is base and in that there is `<div>` and in `<div>` there is `<table>`.

`overflow:scroll;` doesn't seem to work - it hides the overflow content and makes the `<div>` scrollable but the main screen scrolls along with it.

```
#personal_p{
    position:relative;
    width:1100px;
    height:400px;
    max-height:auto;
    top:15px;
    box-shadow:2px 3px 10px grey;
}

#personal_div{
    position:relative;
    top:-400px;
    left:0px;

    overflow-y:scroll;
    width:1090px;
    height:390px;
    /*border:2px solid red;*/
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you are after?

```
#personal_p{
position:relative; 
 margin:10px; 
 overflow-y:scroll;
 width:600px;
height:400px; 
top:15px;
box-shadow:2px 3px 10px grey;
}

#personal_div{
position:relative; 
left:0px; 
/*border:2px solid red;*/
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/GlynneT/kytgLhdd/

Comment: **Exactly**  what i wanted .. :) _**Thank you** so much_ @Glynne

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a separate page with just the table then add it back in to the page you want with `<iframe>` tags.

-http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

you can also reference a .html page not just a link.

Comment: Not what i wanted but **Thanx** for Reply :)